How to rebuild StateProvider in RiverPod Flutter
recently I was reading about Riverpod State management in Flutter, and I started using it in my App, I wanted to give a random List of image paths when I press refresh button on my Ui,I made a StateProvider to get the List of random paths from Unsplash url, here is my code
final imgsPathsProvider = StateProvider<List<String>>((ref) {
  return List.generate(
      10,
      (index) =>
          'https://source.unsplash.com/random/?night&${Random().nextInt(1000)}');
});

now I used this provider in my UI when I'm pressing on refresh button, here is my code and it worked well:
 TextButton(
      onPressed: () {
        ref.read(imgsPathsProvider.notifier).update((state) {
          return List.generate(
              10,
              (index) =>
                 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/?night&${Random().nextInt(1000)}');
        });
      },
      child: const Text('refresh'))

the thing is when I press refresh button I want to rebuild the provider to get a random List of images, instead of repeating the code, I feel like I broke DRY principle, this is very simple use case so I used StateProvider instead of NotifierProvider, should I use NotifierProvider instead, and define a method and call it in the UI when pressing refresh? or is there any method to rebuild the state of my StateProvider?

Avoid legacy riverpod tools. In brief, avoid legacy ChangeNotifier, StateNotifier (and their providers) and StateProvider.  Use only Provider, FutureProvider, StreamProvider, and Notifier, AsyncNotifier, StreamNotifier (and their providers).

And specifically, StateProvider<List> is going to be problematic, because List mutations won't trigger events.

If you simply want to recompute a provider, there is an invalidate method available for WidgetRef.
onPressed: () {
  ref.invalidate(imgsPathsProvider);
},

Note that invalidate also works on family provider with or without family parameters, meaning that you could invalidate all family provider or a specific family provider.
And yes, it is recommended to use NotifierProvider instead of StateProvider mainly for the below reasons.

The logic to update the StateProvider is place inside the widget and it is not reusable and hard to maintain. Using NotifierProvider can centralise the logic.
Riverpod Code generation does not support StateProvider.


Thank you, invalidated method worked well, I did not know about it before and thank you for your opinion about what is recommended, but my app is so simple just refreshing the list to get new images and display them in a grid, and no more action needed or user interaction, so I think using StateProvider to provider the list of random images and when pressing refresh and recomputing the provider by this line in the UI will be good, right? but its a good point to mention that riverpod code generation does not support stateprovider. thank you again

The update function will rebuild the state but you need to watch the provider to do the same.
Use this variable to watch the provider and use this in the view that is displaying the images.
final images = ref.watch(imgsPathsProvider);

Alternatively you can aslo use this to update the state.
ref.read(imgsPathProvider.notifier).state = List.generate(
              10,
              (index) =>
                 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/?night&${Random().nextInt(1000)}');
        });


thank you but the update function did not work, when I return the same state so I had to return the list again and broke DRY principle, the same thing if i assigned the list to the state again ref.read(imgsPathProvider.notifier).state = , i will be repeating the code, so check the answer that I accepted it as a true answer, it worked for me
